# Jsp java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "atividade"

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm having this error regarding the webapp i'm doing in spring mvc
java.lang.NumberFormatException and it is not an intger but a string
This is my Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "atividades", schema = "spring")
public class Atividades implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int idAtividades;
    private int idUtilizador;
    private Integer idCargo;
    private String atividade;
    private String local;
    private String descricao;
    private String objetivos;
    private String periodo;
    private String previsaoMes;
    private Date dataPrevista;
    private Time hora;
    private String orcamento;
    private String destinatarios;
    private String observacoes;
    private int idAno;
    private Timestamp registado;
    private byte plano;
    private String realizado;
    private String motivo;
    private String file;
    private AppUser appUserByIdUtilizador;
    private Cargos cargosByIdCargo;
    private AnoEscolar anoEscolarByIdAno;
    private Collection<AvaliacaoAtividades> avaliacaoAtividadesByIdAtividades;

    public Atividades() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_atividades")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int getIdAtividades() {
        return idAtividades;
    }

    public void setIdAtividades(int idAtividades) {
        this.idAtividades = idAtividades;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id_utilizador")
    public int getIdUtilizador() {
        return idUtilizador;
    }

    public void setIdUtilizador(int idUtilizador) {
        this.idUtilizador = idUtilizador;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id_cargo")
    public Integer getIdCargo() {
        return idCargo;
    }

    public void setIdCargo(Integer idCargo) {
        this.idCargo = idCargo;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "atividade")
    public String getAtividade() {
        return atividade;
    }

    public void setAtividade(String atividade) {
        this.atividade = atividade;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "local")
    public String getLocal() {
        return local;
    }

    public void setLocal(String local) {
        this.local = local;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "descricao")
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "objetivos")
    public String getObjetivos() {
        return objetivos;
    }

    public void setObjetivos(String objetivos) {
        this.objetivos = objetivos;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "periodo")
    public String getPeriodo() {
        return periodo;
    }

    public void setPeriodo(String periodo) {
        this.periodo = periodo;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "previsao_mes")
    public String getPrevisaoMes() {
        return previsaoMes;
    }

    public void setPrevisaoMes(String previsaoMes) {
        this.previsaoMes = previsaoMes;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "data_prevista")
    public Date getDataPrevista() {
        return dataPrevista;
    }

    public void setDataPrevista(Date dataPrevista) {
        this.dataPrevista = dataPrevista;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "hora")
    public Time getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public void setHora(Time hora) {
        this.hora = hora;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "orcamento")
    public String getOrcamento() {
        return orcamento;
    }

    public void setOrcamento(String orcamento) {
        this.orcamento = orcamento;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "destinatarios")
    public String getDestinatarios() {
        return destinatarios;
    }

    public void setDestinatarios(String destinatarios) {
        this.destinatarios = destinatarios;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "observacoes")
    public String getObservacoes() {
        return observacoes;
    }

    public void setObservacoes(String observacoes) {
        this.observacoes = observacoes;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id_ano")
    public int getIdAno() {
        return idAno;
    }

    public void setIdAno(int idAno) {
        this.idAno = idAno;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "registado")
    public Timestamp getRegistado() {
        return registado;
    }

    public void setRegistado(Timestamp registado) {
        this.registado = registado;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "plano")
    public byte getPlano() {
        return plano;
    }

    public void setPlano(byte plano) {
        this.plano = plano;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "realizado")
    public String getRealizado() {
        return realizado;
    }

    public void setRealizado(String realizado) {
        this.realizado = realizado;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "motivo")
    public String getMotivo() {
        return motivo;
    }

    public void setMotivo(String motivo) {
        this.motivo = motivo;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "file")
    public String getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_utilizador", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public AppUser getAppUserByIdUtilizador() {
        return appUserByIdUtilizador;
    }

    public void setAppUserByIdUtilizador(AppUser appUserByIdUtilizador) {
        this.appUserByIdUtilizador = appUserByIdUtilizador;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_cargo", referencedColumnName = "id_cargo", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Cargos getCargosByIdCargo() {
        return cargosByIdCargo;
    }

    public void setCargosByIdCargo(Cargos cargosByIdCargo) {
        this.cargosByIdCargo = cargosByIdCargo;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_ano", referencedColumnName = "id_ano", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public AnoEscolar getAnoEscolarByIdAno() {
        return anoEscolarByIdAno;
    }

    public void setAnoEscolarByIdAno(AnoEscolar anoEscolarByIdAno) {
        this.anoEscolarByIdAno = anoEscolarByIdAno;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "atividadesByIdAtividades")
    public Collection<AvaliacaoAtividades> getAvaliacaoAtividadesByIdAtividades() {
        return avaliacaoAtividadesByIdAtividades;
    }

    public void setAvaliacaoAtividadesByIdAtividades(Collection<AvaliacaoAtividades> avaliacaoAtividadesByIdAtividades) {
        this.avaliacaoAtividadesByIdAtividades = avaliacaoAtividadesByIdAtividades;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Atividades{" +
                "idAtividades=" + idAtividades +
                ", idUtilizador=" + idUtilizador +
                ", idCargo=" + idCargo +
                ", atividade='" + atividade + '\'' +
                ", local='" + local + '\'' +
                ", descricao='" + descricao + '\'' +
                ", objetivos='" + objetivos + '\'' +
                ", periodo='" + periodo + '\'' +
                ", previsaoMes='" + previsaoMes + '\'' +
                ", dataPrevista=" + dataPrevista +
                ", hora=" + hora +
                ", orcamento='" + orcamento + '\'' +
                ", destinatarios='" + destinatarios + '\'' +
                ", observacoes='" + observacoes + '\'' +
                ", idAno=" + idAno +
                ", registado=" + registado +
                ", plano=" + plano +
                ", realizado='" + realizado + '\'' +
                ", motivo='" + motivo + '\'' +
                ", file='" + file + '\'' +
                ", appUserByIdUtilizador=" + appUserByIdUtilizador +
                ", cargosByIdCargo=" + cargosByIdCargo +
                ", anoEscolarByIdAno=" + anoEscolarByIdAno +
                ", avaliacaoAtividadesByIdAtividades=" + avaliacaoAtividadesByIdAtividades +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And my Dao

```
public interface AtividadesDao {

    void save(Atividades a);

    void edit(Atividades a,int id);

    void deleteById(int id);

    List <Atividades> listAllAtividades();

}
```

My DaoImpl

```
@Override
public List<Atividades> listAllAtividades() {
    session.openSession();
    return session.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT ATIVIDADE, LOCAL, DATA_PREVISTA, TIME_FORMAT(HORA, '%H:%i') AS HORA FROM ATIVIDADES WHERE DATA_PREVISTA BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)").list();
}
```

my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String homePage(ModelMap model) {
    //Lista as atividades da semana
    List<Atividades> atividades = as.listAllAtividades();
    model.addAttribute("atividades", atividades);
    System.out.println(atividades);
    //noinspection SpringMVCViewInspection
    return "index";
}
```

and my jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${atividades}" var="ati">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>${ati.atividade}</td>
                                        <td>${ati.local}</td>
                                        <td>${ati.dataPrevista}</td>
                                        <td>${ati.hora}</td>
                                        <td>${ati.destinatarios}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </c:forEach>
```

The error

```
        org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/index.jsp at line 48

            45: <tbody>
            46:   <c:forEach items="${atividades}" var="ati">
            47:     <tr>
            48:        <td>${ati.atividade}</td>
            49:        <td>${ati.local}</td>
            50:        <td>${ati.dataPrevista}</td>
            51:        <td>${ati.hora}</td>
```

The line

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "atividade"
```

Any help fixing this issue?

**UPDATE**

With the updated query in my server uotput i have this response

```
Hibernate: 
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    ATIVIDADES 
WHERE
    DATA_PREVISTA BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

***[[Ljava.lang.Object;@2a6e2a42]***

So what i see i'm getting an object

Comment: and after the update. Are you getting the same error?

Comment: Yes, i do, the same

Comment: mhm, there must something wrong with the contents of the List. That's all I can come to think of.

Comment: Can you give us some sample of the altividade field and also can you verify data in DB contains all the number data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createSQLQuery.list()` will always return `List<Object[]>` (if multiple columns are specified). However, you can get `List<Atividades>` by using below method:

```
@Override
public List<Atividades> listAllAtividades() {
    session.openSession();
    return session.getCurrentSession()
                  .createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM ATIVIDADES WHERE DATA_PREVISTA BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)")
                  .addEntity(Atividades.class)
                  .list();
}
```

You can read about entity queries in [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html)

Comment: Thank you very much all of you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This line: `List<Atividades> atividades = as.listAllAtividades();` might not give you what you want. When you choose individual fields in the SQL Query you get `List<Object[]>` instead of `List<Entity_You_Wanted>`. Though you are getting it as a  `List<Atividades>`which is weird. Anyways, Try getting the whole entity instead in you query. Something like `SELECT * FROM` or `SELECT FROM Atividade WHERE..` if HQL. Let me now if it works.

Disclaimer: I might be wrong because the fact that you can return a `List<Atividades>` is a little strange to me.